# Tomcat Webapp Won't Launch

Tags: apache, tomcat

Im new to tomcat and I'm having issues launching my tomcat webapp. 
I have tomcat setup on localhost:8081 and the tomcat main page comes up if I put localhost:8081 in the address bar after launching launch-tomcat.bat

[image]

I've been stuck on this issue for a week now so I'm going to try and provide as much information as possible. Please let me know if you needed any other additional information.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

If I try to go to http://localhost:8081/week12app_novak/
I get the following error.
[image]

Here's a screenshot of the directory path to the webapp.

Also here's a pastebin of catalina.2015-11-22.log http://pastebin.com/U2Dqjqhc

[image]
launch-tomcat.bat

```
setlocal
SET TOOLS_HOME=C:\projects\tools\
SET TOMCAT_HOME=tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14
::SET CATALINA_HOME=D:\tools\java\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14
::SET CATALINA_HOME=C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14
SET CATALINA_HOME=%TOOLS_HOME%%TOMCAT_HOME%
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65

:: Start Tomcat

%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\startup.bat

endlocal
```

UPDATED IMAGE AFTER ADDED CODE TO WEB.XML
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your `web.xml`, but it probably does not have a welcome file list. If you don't supply one, Tomcat will look for `index.html`, `index.htm`, or `index.jsp` in the `week12app_novak` directory when you try to access http://localhost:8080/week12app_novak/.

You could rename `user-accounts.html` to `index.html`. Or you could add a `welcome-file-list` tag block to your `web.xml`.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/user-accounts.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: If I change user-accounts.html to index.html I can get the webapp to load, but some content isn't showing up correctly. I need this to work without changing to index.html and if I put the welcome xml code you provided in web.xml, I get what you see in the screenshot closest to the bottom of the page. How can I get this webapp to load while keeping the user-accounts.html file name the same?

Comment: It loads, but it also says ATM Project - Accounts <% Object obj = request.getSession().getAttribute("user"); if( obj instanceof User) { User curUser = (User)obj; out.print(curUser.getFirst() + " " + curUser.getLast()); } %>.I really need it to load with user-accounts.html being the file name that's loaded

Comment: You need to supply more details about your webapp. If you could post the web.xml and the user-accounts.html, that would help. From your last comment, it sounds like the file is a JSP, and if so you should name it user-accounts.jsp so that your script is handled correctly.